# Cannot delete a record in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, delete-record

Hello I am trying to create some pages for a school project. 
The whole topic is about creating,deleting,searching,updating destinations for vacation. I have a problem in deleting a record. I have created an html page with a form in order to receive the name of the destination that you want to delete. Next there is the code of java page i have created. Do you see anything wrong? Because whatever I am trying the record won't be deleted. Thanks

**HTML PAGE**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Insert the destination you want to delete</h1>

        <form action="delete.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="delete">
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Delete!">
        </form>





    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVA PAGE:**

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Delete</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <%

          String name=request.getParameter("name");
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vac",
"user","pass"); 

Statement myStatement=con.createStatement();
String SQLstring="DELETE FROM dest WHERE name= '" +name+ "'";
myStatement.executeUpdate(SQLstring);
myStatement.close();
con.close();
out.println("Destination deleted!"); 

      %>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is there a "name" parameter in your html?

Comment: Also: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. [Please read here](http://bobby-tables.com) to learn about them and how to prevent them.

Answer (score 3):

I think the parameter name is "delete", no "name", according to the form input name.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Antonio Martinez's answer, the parameter name was incorrect (it's not `name` but `delete`). I feel I must post this answer to point out the SQL Injection risk your code shows.

You should *never* build a query the way you're doing (taking outside parameters to build the statement), because it can allow the injection of rogue code. You should *always* use prepared statements to deal with users' input:

```
String sqlString = "delete from dest where name=?";
/* The question-mark is a place holder for the parameter. 
   Notice that you don't need to enclose it in quotes, 
   the prepared statement will take care about that. */
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlString);
/* Notice that nothing is executed here: you're only preparing the
   statement using the SQL string (which includes the place-holder(s)
   for the parameter(s). */
ps.setString(1, delete)
/* Here you assign the parameter(s) value(s) to the prepared statement.
   The parameters are numbered starting from one, and ordered 
   the way they appear in your SQL string. 
   The setXXX() methods of the prepared statement allow you to 
   pass the correct value to the query. Strings, in this case, are 
   properly handled, so any rogue code the user might try to inject will 
   not pass as "executable code", but simply as a string. */
ps.execute();
```

Again, I advice you [read here](http://bobby-tables.com) to learn about SQL injection attacks: What they are, what is the risk posed by them and how to prevent them.